# atom-live-server installed but does not appear in packages and wont run... just nothing

Tags: macos, atom-editor

So I am a bit of a noob but I have installed atom on my mac (editor works fine) and installed live-server.
I am unable to start ls, and although it appears to be installed in settings i.e. I can disable or uninstall it, it is not listed under the packages drop down - also tried the hotkeys for my version.
Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling a few times, even following instructions to remove hidden files etc courtesy of Google. It just looks like its not there...

Versions: atom 1.18.0 X64, live-server 2.1.2, running on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: Solution from github https://github.com/jas-chen/atom-live-server/issues/57